# Why isn't this fetch function returning anything?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a login system using PDO but for some reason my `fetch` function doesn't return anything. I've tried using `print_r` to print out the fetch but it just doesn't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($email));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

if($rowCount < 1) {
    echo "error";
    // header("Location: ../login.php?login=email_error");
    exit();
} else {
    if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {}
        $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
        if($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
            exit();
        } elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
            // Log in the user
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['user_email'];
            echo "no, here!";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably due to `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();` and `{}` after `if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: The former was the problem. But why?

Comment: Oh and those curly braces were put there by mistake, I forgot to undo that change before copying it.

Comment: Once you do a fetch, either `->fetchAll()` or `->fetch()`, it moves the internal pointer to the next result set. Since `->fetchAll()` returns all the results, there was nothing left to fetch with your `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out - your fetching the data twice, you can either comment out this line...

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

As later on you fetch the particular row for the user (the call to `fetch()`)

Or change the following section...

```
} else {
        $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $result[0]['user_pwd']);
        if($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
            exit();
        } elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
            // Log in the user
            $_SESSION['id'] = $result[0]['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $result[0]['user_email'];
            echo "no, here!";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

So your referring back to the data fetched in the `fetchAll()`.  As `fetchAll()` returns an array of records, you need to use `$result[0]` to reference the first row in the result set.